# Printing shem hashem

Tags: halacha, writing-printing, shemos-sacred-names

My siddur does not have the laining for rosh chodesh so I want to print a copy of it. Is there anything wrong with intentionally printing it without removing shem hashem?

Comment: When you say "print a copy of it", do you mean "photocopy it"? Also, are you asking only as regards the name-of-_Hashem_ issue (disregarding, e.g.. copyright issues)?

Comment: As [@msh210 answered](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14914/5), I think you're fine printing it. The question is, [what to do with it when you're done with it](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/159/5)?

Comment: @msh210. I mean taking the text from mechon mamre or bar ilan and printing it, not photocopying

Comment: Or is the issue one of copyright?

Comment: Does anyone else find it somewhat ironic that the text of the torah can be copyrighted (even if the copyright is technically on the formatting)?

Comment: @AriA http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10877/759

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56866/explicit-shaimos-printed-in-prayer-books?noredirect=1#comment176157_56866

Comment: [similar](/q/101405/170)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

People [publish *sidurim* with *Hashem*'s name](/q/56866) all the time. That's what you're doing, albeit by photocopy (or laser printing) rather than by offset. So you're in the clear. (This answer doesn't, however, touch on copyright concerns.) As always, though, for practical *halacha*, consult your rabbi rather than relying on what you read on this site.

Comment: The gemara in Shabbos 115b cites a Tosefta seemingly condemning those who publish prayer-books (and amulets) with G-d's name: "...מכאן אמרו כותבי ברכות כשורפי תורה".