# When is a copyright violated?

Tags: jewish-books, intellectual-property

Most books claim copyright. This is a legal right that grants the creator of an original work exclusive rights for its use and distribution.

What is the Torah formulation of copyright?

How far does this copyright extend? For example, would a translation of the book without the approval of the author constitute a violation of the copyright?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10877/can-a-book-with-ancient-text-really-be-copyright

Comment: Yamin, I have edited your question intending to make it clearer. If you do not like my edit, you can always roll back to your original text.

Comment: This seems too broad. I can imagine entire books devoted to answering this question.

Comment: @CashCow That asks why certain books can be copyrighted, not if there is a halakhic basis for copyright

Comment: There is no halakhic equivalent to copyright.

Comment: @ShamanSTK There is a halachic concept of intellectual property.

Comment: @CashCow what's your source?

Comment: highly related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9473/759